# C++ - Get the "difference" of 2 strings like git

Tags: c++, string, git, comparison

I'm currently working on a project which includes a Win32 console program on my Windows 10 PC and an app for my Windows 10 Mobile Phone. It's about controlling the master and audio session volumes on my PC over the app on my Windows Phone.

The "little" problem I have right now is to get the "difference" between 2 strings.

Let's take these 2 strings for example:

```
std::string oldVolumes = "MASTER:50:SYSTEM:50:STEAM:100:UPLAY:100";
std::string newVolumes = "MASTER:30:SYSTEM:50:STEAM:100:ROCKETLEAGUE:80:CHROME:100";
```

Now I want to compare these 2 strings. Lets say I explode each string to a vector with the ":" as delimiter (I have a function named explode to cut the given string by the delimiter and write the string before into a vector).

Good enough. But as you can see, in the old string there's UPLAY with the value 100, but it's missing in the new string. Also, there are 2 new values (RocketLeague and Chrome), which are missing in the old one. But not only the "audio sessions/names" are different, the values are different too.

What I want now is for each session, which is in both strings (like master and system), to compare the values and if the the new value is different to the old one, I want to append this change into another string, like:

```
std::string volumeChanges = "MASTER:30"; // Cause Master is changed, System not
```

If there's a session in the old string, but not in the new one, I want to append:

```
std::string volumeChanges = "MASTER:30:REMOVE:UPLAY";
```

If there's a session in the new one, which is missing in the old string, I want to append it like that:

```
std::string volumeChanges = "MASTER:30:REMOVE:UPLAY:ADD:ROCKETLEAGUE:ROCKETLEAGUE:80:ADD:CHROME:CHROME:100";
```

The volumeChanges string is just to show you, what I need. I'll try to make a better one afterwards.

Do you have any ideas of how to implement such a comparison? I don't need a specific code example or something, just some ideas of how I could do that in theory. It's like GIT at least. If you make changes in a text file, you see in red the deleted text and in green the added one. Something similar to this, just with strings or vectors of strings.

Comment: I used a loop and compared character by character.  If the characters are not equal, break out of the loop.  The main reason for the loop is that I wanted the indices where the two strings differ.

Comment: Determining differences between two sets of data, be it text, or something else, is a science in of itself. Lots of code has been written, over the years (even decades) to find best ways to do it. Unfortunately, there is no magic button one can push, and out pops the code to do it. For simple use cases, probably coding a character by character comparison search would probably be the best thing you can hope for.

Comment: You might start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance (yours is more a string-to-string edit / correction problem, rather than a distance measurement, but the linked page seems much more informative here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Lets say I explode each string to a vector with the ":" as delimiter (I have a function named explode to cut the given string by the delimiter and write the string before into a vector).

I'm going to advise you further extend that logic to separate them into `property` objects that discretely maintain a name + value:

```
struct property {
    std::string name;
    in32_t value;

    bool same_name(property const& o) const {
        return name == o.name;
    }

    bool same_value(property const& o) const {
        return value == o.value;
    }

    bool operator==(property const& o) const {
        return same_name(o) && same_value(o);
    }

    bool operator<(property const& o) const {
        if(!same_name(o)) return name < o.name;
        else return value < o.value;
    }
};
```

This will dramatically simplify the logic needed to work out which properties were changed/added/removed.

The logic for "tokenizing" this kind of string isn't too difficult:

```
std::set<property> tokenify(std::string input) {
    bool finding_name = true;
    property prop;
    std::set<property> properties;
    while (input.size() > 0) {
        auto colon_index = input.find(':');
        if (finding_name) {
            prop.name = input.substr(0, colon_index);
            finding_name = false;
        }
        else {
            prop.value = std::stoi(input.substr(0, colon_index));
            finding_name = true;
            properties.insert(prop);
        }
        if(colon_index == std::string::npos) 
            break;
        else 
            input = input.substr(colon_index + 1);
    }
    return properties;
}
```

Then, the function to get the difference:

```
std::string get_diff_string(std::string const& old_props, std::string const& new_props) {
    std::set<property> old_properties = tokenify(old_props);
    std::set<property> new_properties = tokenify(new_props);

    std::string output;

    //We first scan for properties that were either removed or changed
    for (property const& old_property : old_properties) {
        auto predicate = [&](property const& p) {
            return old_property.same_name(p);
        };
        auto it = std::find_if(new_properties.begin(), new_properties.end(), predicate);
        if (it == new_properties.end()) {
            //We didn't find the property, so we need to indicate it was removed
            output.append("REMOVE:" + old_property.name + ':');
        }
        else if (!it->same_value(old_property)) {
            //Found the property, but the value changed.
            output.append(it->name + ':' + std::to_string(it->value) + ':');
        }
    }

    //Finally, we need to see which were added.
    for (property const& new_property : new_properties) {
        auto predicate = [&](property const& p) {
            return new_property.same_name(p);
        };
        auto it = std::find_if(old_properties.begin(), old_properties.end(), predicate);
        if (it == old_properties.end()) {
            //We didn't find the property, so we need to indicate it was added
            output.append("ADD:" + new_property.name + ':' + new_property.name + ':' + std::to_string(new_property.value) + ':');
        }
        //The previous loop detects changes, so we don't need to bother here.
    }

    if (output.size() > 0)
        output = output.substr(0, output.size() - 1); //Trim off the last colon

    return output;
}
```

And we can demonstrate that it's working with a simple `main` function:

```
int main() {
    std::string diff_string = get_diff_string("MASTER:50:SYSTEM:50:STEAM:100:UPLAY:100", "MASTER:30:SYSTEM:50:STEAM:100:ROCKETLEAGUE:80:CHROME:100");
    std::cout << "Diff String was \"" << diff_string << '\"' << std::endl;
}
```

Which yields an output (*[according to IDEONE.com](http://ideone.com/g7wB5y)*):

```
Diff String was "MASTER:30:REMOVE:UPLAY:ADD:CHROME:CHROME:100:ADD:ROCKETLEAGUE:ROCKETLEAGUE:80"
```

Which, although the contents are in a slightly different order than your example, still contains all the correct information. The contents are in different order because `std::set` implicitly sorted the attributes by name when tokenizing the properties; if you want to disable that sorting, you'd need to use a different data structure which preserves entry order. I chose it because it eliminates duplicates, which could cause odd behavior otherwise.

Comment: What the.. Even with working code. That's a very nice solution I must say. The order of the sessions doesn't matter at least. I just need this output string for my app to create dynamically object in my ObservableCollection for the slider elements for each session.

Comment: Really, I thank you. Now I just have to understand this line of code:

    auto predicate = [&](property const& p) {
        return old_property.same_name(p);
     };

Could you explain me what [&] means? Or a keyword I should google for to understand it. The other lines, no problem.

Thank you very much, again.

(Wasn't able to edit my above comment cause of the 5 minutes)

Comment: The expression in the form `[](){/*...*/}` is commonly known as a *[Lambda Expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)*, which is a kind of anonymous function. Follow that link for more details about what they are and how they work.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular instance, you could do it as follows:

- Split the old and new strings by the delimiter, and store the results in a vector.
- Loop over the vector with the old data. Look for each word in the vector with new data: e.g. find("MASTER").
- If not found add "REMOVE:MASTER" to your results.
- If found, compare the numbers and add it to the results if it has been changed.
- The added string can be found by looping over the new string and searching for the words in the old string.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you enumerate some features (in your case for example: UPLAY present, REMOVE is present, ...)

for every one of those assign a weight if the two strings differs for the given feature.

At the end sum up weights for the features presents in one string and absent in the other and get a number.
This number should represent what you are looking for.

You can adjust weights until you are satisfied with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer will give you some new thoughts. In fact, by tweaking the current code, you can find all the missing words.

```
std::vector<std::string> splitString(const std::string& str, const char delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> out;

    std::stringstream ss(str);
    std::string s;
    while (std::getline(ss, s, delim)) {
        out.push_back(s);
    }

    return out;
}

std::vector<std::string> missingWords(const std::string& first, const std::string& second)
{
    std::vector<std::string> missing;

    const auto firstWords = splitString(first, ' ');
    const auto secWords = splitString(second, ' ');

    size_t i = 0, j = 0;
    for(; i < firstWords.size();){
        auto findSameWord = std::find(secWords.begin() + j, secWords.end(), firstWords[i]);
        if(findSameWord == secWords.end()) {
            missing.push_back(firstWords[i]);
            j++;
        } else {
            j = distance(secWords.begin(), findSameWord);
        }
        i++;
    }

    return missing;
}
```